# Echarts multiple line chart

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, echarts

I'm working on echarts line chart and I figured out that I have an issue with multiple line chart. For example when I have two series with different size (First serie length is 7 and the second one is 1), the chart shows wrong data.

**The point on the left is supposed to be on the last day not the first one:**

[image]

Can someone give me some help about this bug please ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the first six days to 0

```
 series: [
    {
      name: 'Email',
      type: 'line',
      stack: 'Total',
      data: [120, 132, 101, 134, 90, 230, 210]
    },
    {
      name: 'Union Ads',
      type: 'line',
      stack: 'Total',
      data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 310]
    },
    // Show only the data you need
    {
      name: 'Union Ads',
      type: 'line',
      stack: 'Total',
      data: [['coordinate',200]]
    },
```

Give me a case that I changed on the official website, and I hope it can be adopted

https://www.makeapie.com/editor.html?c=xAfL5RkD9x&v=1

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It can be a good solution. Is there a way to hide the line chart when the value is equal to 0 and to show only the provided data point?

Comment: This should meet your needs and if there is a problem, give feedback or take it on board